# List Manipulation in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

Given a list such that [[%,A,B,C,%D,E,%],[%,F,G,%,H,I,J,%]] how do I return [[A,B,C],[D,E],[F,G],[H,I,J]]

I tried the following code:

```
filtertolists([],[]).
filtertolists([Head|Tail],Y):-
     (Head = '%' ->
      filtertolists(Tail,Y)).
```

I want to get the first element from the list of lists, and check whether members of the list are equal to '%' and start creating the list to be given as output, but after getting the head how do I check each element in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would split the task into two tasks:

1. iterating over the list of lists
2. removing the elements of one list

My resulting sourceocde would look like this:

```
filtertolists([],[]).
filtertolists([List|Tail], [FilteredList|FilteredTail]):-
     filterList(List, FilteredList), 
     filtertolists(Tail, FilteredTail).

filterList([], []).
 % your filter code for one list goes here .
filterList(...).
filterList(...).
```

Comment: Given an Input X =[%,A,B,C,%,D,E,%] need an output in a list like [[A,B,C],[D,E]], is there a way to create a new list everytime I encounter'%'?

Comment: Yes there is. Zou would need something like `filterList(List, CurrentList, ResultList)´.